# Calling a user selectable string in another class

Tags: java, string, class

So I have made this little piece of code that opens a filebrowser and lets you select a file and converts this into the string "content". Now I want to call this string into another class in order to do something with it but it doesnt seem to work. For now I just want the other class to paste the contents of the string into the console just to see if it works.

Here is the code for the filechooser

```
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Bladeren");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
            int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            String content;
            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                System.out.println("Selected file: " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                content = readFile(selectedFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                System.out.println(content);
                textArea.setText(content);

            }

        }
    });
```

And here is just the simple call to the other class

```
    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Encrypt");
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Encrypter.main();
        }
    });
```

And here is the other class

```
public class Encrypter extends GUI{

public static void main (){
    System.out.println(GUI.content);


}}
```

I hope I gave enough information thanks in advance!

Comment: The scope of `String content;` is within your action handler, so that is where it can be seen.  if you want to increase its scope then maybe make it a field

Comment: Do you mean like `public static char[] content;`?

Comment: No, not at all.  Make it a field.  If you do not understand what that means that I respectfully suggest that you re-read your java books

Comment: Im very sorry, I just saw something that looked like it but I will indeed research more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `content` `String` outside your `ActionListener` as @ScaryWombat suggested, on the top of your class outside of any methods (make it a instance variable, field).

```
private String content;
```

Then:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Bladeren");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println("Selected file: " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
            content = readFile(selectedFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println(content);
            textArea.setText(content);

        }

    }
});
```

Then change the `main` method of the `Encrypter` class to accept a `String` argument (it's better to change also the name of `main` lets say it `encrypt`):

```
public class Encrypter extends GUI{

public static void encrypt(String content){
        System.out.println(content); 
    }
}
```

Finally, assuming that the following piece of code is in the same class/method as the first piece of code call the `Encrypter.encrypt` from:

```
JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Encrypt");
btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Encrypter.encrypt(content);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I see what is happening now.

Comment: Nice, consider upvoting/accepting as correct the answer (since you are a newcomer, this way StackOverflow works)

Comment: Sorry I did not see the accept answer thing but I did already upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example I wrote in Notepad++ and I hope I didnt slide any error in there!

I hope the example helps you to understand how the concept behind it works

```
public class SOFTest() extends JFrame {

    private TestClass testClass;

    public SOFTest() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        testClass = new TestClass();
        JButton button = new JButton("Print!");
        button.addActionListener(listener -> {
            testClass.storeString("String to store");
            testClass.printString;
        });
        add(button);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class TestClass() {

        private String string;

        public void storeString(String string) {
            this.string = string;
        }

        public void printString() {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this has made some stuff clearer!

Comment: No problem sir!